# Is there a way to insert multiple lines, with labels, dynamically, into a ChartJS Line chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was hoping it's possible as I've been trying to find a way to do this, with a little knowledge of js, and ChartJS. I was hoping to call addData, and fill the lines but I've not figured out a way of mapping which data is for the corresponding label, for each line. My issues are that the objects that I'm passing by JSON, all have have different dates, for different wages;

```
{
  "details": [
    {
     "user": [
       {
          "amount": "15000",
          "startdate": "01/01/2012",
          "enddate": "01/01/2012",
          "id": "23",
        }, {
          "amount": "21000",
          "startdate": "01/01/2013",
          "end": "01/01/2012",
          "id": "23",
        }],
  "user" : etc etc
}
```

And then, catch this with js and arrange with something like this (my actual code is a lot longer so you can see what I'm trying to do);

```
for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < details[i].length; j++)
   {
       addStuffTodataArray(details[i].user[j]);
   }
    var lineData = {
        labels: labelArray,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: JsonData.user,
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: dataArray 
            }
   }
```

At the moment, I'm going to work everything out manually (ie, get the period specified by the user with jQuery, and run through the time frame specified, counting the months and applying a label for each one, then assigning values).

My new way seems like a lot of processing, and I was sure ChartJS would handle this a little better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean several datasets on the chart? If so you can define that as a `datasets` array, in their [example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-introduction) they have two datasets. Otherwise I'm not entirely sure what you mean by multiple lines. This seems like like a question on *"How do I setup my data for a line chart"*, rather than the actual inserting of lines.

Comment: Yeah, several datasets, dynamically created. I've checked their documentation, and you're able to draw values, provided they are there already, but to create them on the fly, I need to be able to add varying amounts of lines (datasets), and varying labels (all of which are in mm/yy format) for each dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this;

```
lineChartData = {}; //declare an object
lineChartData.labels = []; //add 'labels' element to object (X axis)
lineChartData.datasets = []; //add 'datasets' array element to object
var moreData = [[1, 3, 6, 16, 30, 6], [3,2,3,5,1,2], [3,11,23,2,1,9]];
function getLabels()
{
 var labels = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];  
 return labels;
}

for (line = 0; line < moreData.length; line++) {
    y = [];
    lineChartData.datasets.push({}); //create a new line dataset
    dataset = lineChartData.datasets[line]
    dataset.fillColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    if (moreData[line][0] == 1){
        dataset.strokeColor = "rgba(0,0,205,1)";
    } else {
        dataset.strokeColor = "rgba(200,200,200,1)";
    }
    dataset.data = []; //contains the 'Y; axis data

    for (x = 0; x < getLabels().length; x++) {
        labels = getLabels();
        for (var k = 0; k < moreData[line].length; k++){
        y.push( moreData[line][k]);
        }

        if (line === 0)
            lineChartData.labels.push(labels[x]);
    }

    lineChartData.datasets[line].data = y;
}

ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1").getContext("2d");
myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a guess.  I haven't tried this, but based on the [structure of the datasets](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure), I'm thinking you can add a dataset to the array of data and then call `update()`;

```
//here's the new dataset you want to add
var myNewDataset = {
        label: "My third dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    };

//push that onto the datasets array
lineData.datasets.push(myNewDataset);

//call the update method to render the new data
myLineChart.update();
```

Update method is described here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-prototype-methods

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the Chart.Scatter extension (http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/). This is also linked to from the Chart.js documentation (see http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-community-extensions)

Chart.Scatter supports date scales, which would get rid of the

> At the moment, I'm going to work everything out manually (ie, get the
>   period specified by the user with jQuery, and run through the time
>   frame specified, counting the months and applying a label for each
>   one, then assigning values).

that you are doing (you'd still have to to reformat your data structure to fit in with the data structure expected by Chart.Scatter)